# Jenkinsfile pipeline not checking out git

Tags: selenium, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkinsfile failed to pull my selenium code to run automated test, I tried different methods but am still failed to achieve what I need. I think am going in wrong direction. Please correct me if am wrong

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checkout'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Clean Build'
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            when { branch 'develop' }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
        }

        stage('Integration Test') {
            steps {
                node("Android-Build") {
                    def mvnHome = tool 'Maven'
                    stage 'Integration Test'
                    git url: 'git@bitbucket.org:automation-web.git', branch: 'feature/WebAutomation'
                    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn compile"
                    stage 'Test'
                    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn test"
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
checkout([
   $class: 'GitSCM', 
   branches: [[name: 'feature/WebAutomation']], 
   doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
   extensions: [], 
   submoduleCfg: [], 
   userRemoteConfigs: [[
       credentialsId: 'xxx', 
       url: 'git@bitbucket.org:automation-web.git'
   ]]
])
```

instead of:

```
git url: 'git@bitbucket.org:automation-web.git', branch: 'feature/WebAutomation'
```

Solution2:

```
 stage('Integration Test') {
             steps {
                 script {
             def mvnHome = tool 'Maven'
                 checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [],submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url:'git@bitbucket.org:automation-web.git']]])
                 sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn compile"
                 sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn test"
             }
         }
         }
```

U cant put stage in stage. Check graph declarative pipeline: [graph](https://postimg.cc/1VrDwNhJ)

Comment: I don't have a credentialId, as I am using ssh key. Can I specify it as none?

Comment: Also I am getting below error,

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 81: Expected a step @ line 81, column 21.
                       def mvnHome = tool 'Maven'

Comment: @GoSmash check my 2 solution

Comment: Yeah you re right I just updated it already on my script, but your 2 solution is missing node? where it has to be included?